# Connect to Database directly via Mongo Compass

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-compass

Via shell, I can directly connect to mongo database with this string

```
mongo --ssl host1,host2:port/MyDataBase...
```

And I land directly on the MyDataBase.

Is there a similar way to do it in Compass? I get connected to whole server and I can see all the other databases. I just want to connect to MyDataBase.

Comment: Hey there, I believe I know the answer, just give a minute to write it down!

Comment: Hey there, I believe I know what you want, you want to connect using a string in compass, right?

Answer (score 0):

I am using the lattest version of Compass, so it may differ from your current version.
It is important the you are in the network of the server, or use a VPN connection, otherwise, it does not work.

**Step 1**

[image]

**Step 2**

[image]

Please,let me know if that works!